# How to recycle/dispose bitmap used by theme

Tags: android, xamarin.android

my Xamarin.Android application use simple splash screen technique of applying Theme to Splash activity:

```
<resources>
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bluebg</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

and

```
[Activity(Label = "Splushy Splushy", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/SplashTheme")]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{ ... }
```

But it seems like the image used on splashscreen (PNG, 80 KB) take something like 12 MB in memory (that is the difference between memory usage with and without splash) for the whole time my app is running (another activity, never going back to splash screen naturally).

Is there any way to get rid of the resources used by theme of the activity, so my memory footprint dont get unnecessarily big? Thanks.

Comment: Any progress on this one? Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Tried to convert images to jpg and put into drawable-nodpi, but this does not help much

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this to the comment but could not.

Did you try closing your splash activity after you open the new one?

```
StartActivity(typeof(NextActivity));
this.Finish();
```